# Mysql complex query, group by with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, limit

I've the following table

`store_visits: (store_id, city_id, date, visits, ...)`

I want to select the maximum 5 stores ordered by visits.

```
SELECT X.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      store_id, SUM(visits) as sum_visits FROM store_visits
    WHERE 
      (date <= '2014-06-28' AND  date >= '2014-06-27') 
    AND 
      store_visits.city_id = 2 
    GROUP BY 
      store_id 
    ORDER BY 
      sum_visits desc
  ) X 
LIMIT 5
```

I was wondering if there's a way to enhance the query to eleminate the temporary table and filesort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(visits) AS sum_visits 
FROM store_visits sv
WHERE sv.date <= '2014-06-28' AND sv.date >= '2014-06-27' AND sv.city_id = 2 
GROUP BY store_id 
ORDER BY sum_visits DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I don't think it will eliminate the temporary table and filesort